# pySerial - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'serial_port' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pyserial, logfile

I was given this program to keep a log file of what the console prints out of a usb connected device (wireless sensor). It produces the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'serial_port' referenced before assignment.
```

It is `pySerial.py` modified to suit the needs of my application. It logs a part of what the console prints (preferably i would like to log everything)

I am not familiar with python so i couldn't solve this by my self. your help is very welcome!! where has the code gone wrong?

```
import serial
import io
import time        

def serial_com():
    '''Serial communications: get a response'''
    # open serial port
    try:
        serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print("could not open serial port '{}': {}".format('/dev/ttyUSB0', e))

    # read response from serial port
    lines = []
    while True:
        lines = []
        line = serial_port.readline()
        lines = ([time.localtime().tm_hour, 
                  time.localtime().tm_min,
                  time.localtime().tm_sec,
                  line.decode('utf-8').rstrip()])

        # wait for new data after each line
        timeout = time.time() + 10
        while not serial_port.inWaiting() and timeout > time.time():
            pass 
        if not serial_port.inWaiting():
            break 

    #close the serial port
    serial_port.close()

    linesplit = str(lines[3]).split()
    temp1 = -40+0.01*float(linesplit[2])
    output = [lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], temp1]
    return output

def writeXML(lines):
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, ElementTree
    root = Element('CATALOG')
    child1 = SubElement(root, 'Measurement')
    child11 = SubElement(child1, 'Time')
    child11.text = str(lines[0])+':'+str(lines[1])+':'+str(lines[2])
    child12 = SubElement(child1, 'Values')
    child12.text = str(round(lines[3], 2))
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('/var/www/values.xml', 'UTF-8')

while True:
  lines=serial_com()
  writeXML(lines)
  time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit your function when you get an exception:

```
try:
    serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print("could not open serial port '{}': {}".format('/dev/ttyUSB0', e))
    return
```

because if you do get the exception, `serial_port` is never set, leading to your `UnboundLocalError` exception.

I used `return` here as an example; your script breaks either way. You probably should re-raise the exception, or return a suitable default value.

Comment: That would cause an exception to be raised in `writeXML()` due to that function assuming the `lines` variable will be a list (or other sequence) of a specified size and not `None`. As the script is currently written, it would be better to either reraise the exception after the printed message or let it be raised without the try-catch block (though that would lose the current printed message). Assigning a default list to `lines` in the bottom while loop wouldn't be a good idea as it wouldn't really make sense to continuously write out dummy XML data if there's an error.

Comment: @JAB: Yup, qualified it a little more.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. as i said before i don't know python at all...so when you say reraise the exception you mean type

    except serial.SerialException as e:

 again after the print ("could not opet....") message ?

i tried that and it produces a different error message. same when i type return after the print command.

Comment: maybe you have a ready to go program for loging usb input that i can use instead of fixing this code? (one that logs all the output of the consol)

Comment: In this case I'd not catch the exception at all; unless you know how to programmatically recover from that exception.

Comment: if i loose the exception it then pops SyntaxError: invalid syntax on lines = []...